# Intersection curve parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

How can we find parametrization of the intersection curve between a pseudo-sphere and sphere ?

Elimination of variables appears not readily amenable/elegant. Thanks for the same.

[image: sph & pseudo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $z \gt 0$ half of a pseudosphere with radius $r$ is a surface of revolution (rotated around the $z$ axis) described by
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x(t) &= r t - r \tanh t \\
y(t) &= r \operatorname{sech} t = \frac{r}{\cosh t} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $0 \lt t \in \mathbb{R}$.

This intersects a circle of radius $r$ centered at origin when
$$x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 = r^2$$
i.e.
$$(r t - r \tanh t)^2 + \frac{r^2}{(\cosh t)^2} - r^2 = 0$$
The degenerate sphere case ($r = 0$) is uninteresting, so we can assume $r \gt 0$.  For $t \gt 0$, $\cosh t \gt 0$, so we can divide the equation by $t r^2$ and multiply by $\cosh t$, getting
$$\begin{aligned}
t \cosh t - 2 \sinh t &= 0 \\
t \cosh t &= 2 \sinh t \\
t &= 2 \tanh t \\
\end{aligned}$$
which has only one solution for $0 \lt t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$t \approx 1.91500804815453748135300306100481565057336256878593...$$

Because both shapes are symmetric around the $z$ axis, the intersection is a circle of radius $y(t)$ perpendicular to the $z$ axis at $z = x(t)$, i.e.
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
R = y(t) &\approx 0.28841990894499 \, r \\
z = x(t) &\approx 0.95750402407727 \, r \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Three circles having center on $z$ axis at about $C_1(0,0,-0.95936);\;C_2(0,0,0);\;C_3(0,0,-0.95936)$ and radius  about $r_1=r_3=0.28786$
and $r_2=1$

This is the best I could do, since are involved transcendent function an exact solution is impossible to get.

Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Please check. Pseudosphere has a $z$ axis of symmetry not containing the cusp,  running to the right.

Comment: @Narasimham It rotates along the other axis. Ok.

Comment: This is not a pseudosphere.

Comment: Now it is a pseudosphere. The intersection is the union of three circles. @Narasimham

Comment: Radii should be 0.2879 approx.

Comment: @Narasimham Thak you for the correction